# How HBase describe table in hbase shell?

Tags: hbase

I didn't find a source which tells me in details how HBase describe the table.
I am not able to find the fields.
e.g.

```
hbase(main):006:0> describe 'cdap_system:artifact.meta'
Table cdap_system:artifact.meta is ENABLED
cdap_system:artifact.meta, {TABLE_ATTRIBUTES => {coprocessor$1 => '/cdap/cdap/lib/coprocessor-4.3.4-1522017174177-HBASE_12_CDH57.jar|co.cask.cdap.data2.transaction.copr
ocessor.hbase12cdh570.DefaultTransactionProcessor|1073741823|', METADATA => {'cdap.hbase.version' => '1.2-cdh5.7', 'cdap.version' => '4.3.4-1522017174177', 'dataset.tab
le.prefix' => 'cdap'}}
COLUMN FAMILIES DESCRIPTION
{NAME => 'd', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', VERSIONS => '2147483647', IN_MEMORY => 'false', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', COMP
RESSION => 'SNAPPY', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}
1 row(s) in 0.0190 seconds
```

here what is TABLE_ATTRIBUTES?

Answer (score 0):

HBase is schemaless and does not know anything about your columns. Even the notion of `column-family` is very technical rather than logical, as you can in see the description of your column-family 'd':

```
{NAME => 'd', ... TTL => 'FOREVER', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY',  BLOCKSIZE => '65536' ...}
```

^^ hbase only cares about such properties of your table.

Comment: from Name we guess it is a name, similarly with the rest.
so what is meant by TABLE_ATTRIBUTES? how i come to know in hbase what i called as TABLE_ATTRIBUTES

Comment: sorry, I thought meant you can't find the columns. On a second read it is clear that you asked specifically about table attributes. Maybe this can help? https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/21e02813fedc6846c9ef381e1ff9b49534f20ec9/hbase-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/TableDescriptorBuilder.java#L1045